# DataFrame apply and return variably many rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column(say `x`) on which I want to apply a non-trivial function that would result in multiple columns(fixed) and multiple(unknown) rows. Is there any way to do this elegantly?

I know that you can do this with multiple columns if you return a `Series`, but returning a `DataFrame` results in apply returning a `Series` of dataframes. My solution goes a bit like this(mock-up):

```
def func(a):
    return pd.DataFrame(np.ones((a, 2)), columns=['one', 'two'])

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': [1, 2, 1]})
pd.concat(df['x'].apply(func).tolist(), ignore_index=True)
```

Is there builtin way of doing this or at least some less contrived known solution?

Comment: Your question cannot be effectively answered unless we know exactly what your function is doing with the column, sorry.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ In my particular case I am taking a column of html content, and for each of the html inputs I am extracting the text in each one of the tags and its XPath and putting everyone on their own row. So overall, a lot of computation behind, but the question was about the genera case, as I've been in the situation of needing to do  some complex computation that yield arbitrarily many rows before, without a clear vectorizable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion your solution is nice.

You can use also `list comprehension`:

```
df1 = pd.concat([func(x) for x in df['x']], ignore_index=True)
print (df1)
   one  two
0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0
3  1.0  1.0
```

Or  a little hack - [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `unique default index` (`level=0`):

```
def func(a):
    return pd.DataFrame(np.ones((a.iat[0], 2)), columns=['one', 'two'])


df2 = df.groupby(level=0)['x'].apply(func)
print (df2)
     one  two
0 0  1.0  1.0
1 0  1.0  1.0
  1  1.0  1.0
2 0  1.0  1.0

df2 = df.groupby(level=0)['x'].apply(func).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df2)
   one  two
0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0
3  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Ok this looks interesintg. Might be just what I'm looking for. I do understand however, why thy might not have wanted the same behaviour with `apply` as it destroys the index, whereas this does it explicitly.

Comment: I think there is different behavoiur because [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) vs [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) are implemented different.

Comment: Yeah and I think it is so because for the normal apply it would pretty much be undefined behaviour if the index suddenly expanded.